# How to manipulate WPF window controls (tabs, textboxes, listboxes) from a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm kinda new to WPF. I'm making an app using WPF (all the UI controls are already fixed) and MVVM but most of the events are in the code-behind. I'm in the process of clearing the code-behind but I have codes like (the ones below) to switch through tabs, and to trigger visibility of controls depending on parameters:

```
tabItem1.Selected = true;

textBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

lbxHusbandsWives.Items.Add(txtHusbandsWives.Text + '/' +
   cbxHusbandsWivesCountry.Text + '/' +
   dpHusbandsWives.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

How can I do that in the viewmodel? Well, inside a Command? So I can clear the messy code-behind? Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You should strive to do things like this in Xaml. If you use MVVM your data should be bound to your controls. So lbxHusbandsWives should have a property on a ViewModel bound to its ItemSource to begin with. Then you can change the underlying data and the UI will update accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said many times before, MVVM doesn't mean "no code behind". There are things that you can or should do in code-behind, as long as they are strictly related to the view and are not necessary for the ViewModel to work properly.

That being said, in most cases you don't *need* to do anything in code-behind. You normally use bindings to control the view from the ViewModel. This allows the ViewModel to be completely ignorant of the view: it just exposes properties that the view can access, and sends notifications when the values of the properties change. The ViewModel should definitely *not* manipulate the view or its components.

Everything in the code you posted can be done with bindings in XAML:

- `textBox1.Visibility` can be bound to a bool property of the ViewModel, using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`
- `lbxHusbandsWives.ItemsSource` can be bound to an `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel (an `ObservableCollection` notifies the view when items are added to or removed from it)
- `txtHusbandsWives.Text`, `cbxHusbandsWivesCountry.Text` and `dpHusbandsWives.SelectedDate` can also be bound to properties of the appropriate type

Comment: The visibility change can even be done without converters, using DataTriggers to check a property on the ViewModel.